# ajax, shorten height of each div on success of ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I want to shorten the height of a div inside an ajax response with a class `.shorten-post` and i don't know how to achieve this.

I only want to shorten the ones in the ajax response rather than the whole document

this is currently my script for handling ajax

```
var page = 1;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100) {
        page++;
        loadMoreData(page);
    }
});


function loadMoreData(page){
  $.ajax(
        {
            url: '?page=' + page,
            type: "get",
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $('.ajax-load').show();
            }
        })
        .done(function(profcontent)
        {
            if(profcontent == ""){
                $('.ajax-load').html("No more records found");
                return;
            }
            $('.ajax-load').hide();
            $(profcontent).filter('.shorten-post').each(function(){
              if ($(this).height() > 100) {
                $(this).height(50).css({ 'overflow': 'hidden'});
                $(this).siblings('.toggle-shorten-post').show();
            }});
            $(profcontent).insertBefore("#post-data");

        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
              alert('server not responding...');
        });
}
```

**EDIT**

here is a summary of the code for my profcontent

```
<div id="tu_mainpost_<?php echo($current_post['slug_unique']); ?>" class="tu-post">
    <div class="tu-post-header">
    </div>
    <div class="tu-post-image alt-grid shorten-post">
        <div class="row">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo(base_url('assets/img/uploads/' . $current_post['source_img'])); ?>" style="width: 100%; height: inherit;">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 tu-main-description" style="margin: 10px 0px;">
                <div class="tu-main-description">
                    <p class="wordbreak"><?php echo nl2br($current_post['description']); ?></p>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `profcontent` here ? is it rendered content from server ?Also are you getting any errors when you run this code ?

Comment: yes, prof content is a rendered content from server, and there is no errors. the rendered content does return but the div with class {.shorten-post} doesn't shorten the height

Comment: can you post the `profcontent ` if possible in the question or in a codepen/jsfiddle ? That can help find the issue.

Comment: ill just edit my post and add it there, since my profcontent has alot of html and php in it, ill shorten it to only have the things needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mutate $(profcontent)

```
        if(profcontent == ""){
            $('.ajax-load').html("No more records found");
            return;
        }
        $('.ajax-load').hide();
        var $profcontent = $(profcontent);
        $profcontent.filter('.shorten-post').each(function(){
          if ($(this).height() > 100) {
            $(this).height(50).css({ 'overflow': 'hidden'});
            $(this).siblings('.toggle-shorten-post').show();
        }});
        $profcontent.insertBefore("#post-data");
```